# Does Globally Lipchitz prove a solution exists for all time?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

From ODE I learned if $g$ is Lipchitz on $\mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a unique solution $y:\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ to the IVP 
\begin{eqnarray}
y' &=& g(y)\\
y(t_0) &=& y_0
\end{eqnarray}
where $t_0=0$

From what I understand, since $g$ is globally Lipchitz, then it is locally Lipchitz. From the fact it is locally Lipchitz, I can prove there exist a $c>0$ such that our IVP has a unique solution $y(t)$ on a small interval $[-c,c]$.

What I don't understand is, how does a Globally Lipchitz function implies there exist a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$?

The only thing that comes to mind is this, (continuing from what we previously established) since $g$ is Globally Lipchitz and we have proven there exist a unique solution $y(t)$ on $[-c,c]$, I can pick a $t_1>0\in [-c,c]$ such that we have a new IVP 
\begin{eqnarray}
y' &=& g(y)\\
y(t_1) &=& y_1
\end{eqnarray}
Afterwards, it can be proven that this new IVP has a unique solution on some interval $[-c_1+t_1,c_1+t_1]$. Then you would continue iterating this procedure (making sure to pick $t_i>t_{i-1}$) until you construct $[c,\infty]$. You would apply a similar argument to construct the other half of our interval to get the complete $\mathbb{R}$. My only issue is, what if (let's say) after some large $n$, $[-c_n+t_n,c_n+t_n]$ becomes so small that the maximal interval converges to a fixed point and doesn't reach $\infty$?  How would you prevent that issue from happening?

I'm new to the forum so I hope my question wasn't to vague. If you need me to clarify, please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that $c$ (and the subsequent $t_i$'s) is controlled by the Lipschitz constant. If $g$ is globally Lipschitz, the problem you addressed will not occured. It will occur if $g$ is only locally Lipschitz.

Comment: @JohnMa, thank you for your feedback. I think I understand what you mean. If I understand correctly, since $g$ is globally Lipschitz, the constant $L$ that holds for the entire set $\mathbb{R}^n$ holds for the local neighborhoods (by boundedness), which in turn controls $c$?

Comment: For example if at first the solution is defined for $[-c, c]$, then if you start again at $c/2$, the new one is defined up to $c+ c/2$.......

Comment: @JohnMa, Then if we start again at $c$, the new one is defined up to $c+c$? I'm guessing as long as the Lipschitz constant is global you can proceed to finding a solution on $[−c,c]$, $[−c/2,c+c/2]$, $[−c/2,c+c/2]$,  $[0,c+c]$, and so on through all positive times?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @JohnMa, why would the solution be defined up to $c+c/2$, then $2c$ so on and so forth? Is it by maximal interval of existence?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach based on Gronwall's inequality and the fact that if the maximal interval of existence is $[0,T)$ with $t<\infty$, then $\lim_{t\to T^-}|y(t)|=\infty$.

Suppose $y$ is defined on an interval $[0,T)$ and let $L$ be $g's$ Lipschitz constant. Then
$$
y(t)-y_0=\int_0^sg(y(s))\,ds=g(y_0)\,t+\int_0^t(g(y(s))-g(y_0))\,ds
$$
and
$$
|y(t)-y_0|\le T\,|g(y_0)|+L\int_0^t|y(s)-y_0|\,ds,\quad 0\le t<T.
$$
Gronwall's inequality implies that $y$ is bounded on $[0,T)$, and this in turn implies that the solution is global.

A similar argument works on intervals $(-T,0]$.